# Is there any formal education for programming? Other than a CS degree?

Tags: programming, adult-education

Are there any universities that give you a Bachelor's in programming? I am aware of Computer Science BSc, but it's a little too broad in scope.

Comment: There are [Software Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Software_Engineering) degrees also.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no!

The long answer:
In my opinion if you really just want to focus on programming either a paid programming course could be the correct choice or just self-taught learning by doing. Of course you'll miss lots of theoretical things that will be important for an abstract view of programming. And also more complicated problems might need the theoretical knowledge you would gain at university.

If you want some certification of your knowledge, I would recommend you to gain enough knowledge in a language that has certifications and just get this certification.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will find a *reputable* Bachelor's degree in Computer Programming. Programming is just a tool for the production of "interesting" things. It requires skill to wield that tool, but it isn't, by itself, broad enough to constitute an actual Bachelor's degree.

A Computer Science degree, on the other hand focuses on programming in the first year so that students will be skilled enough in the tool to be able to explore the interesting things like databases, operating systems, artificial intelligence, human factors engineering, and a host of others.

Programming can be fun, but it can also be used to explore and understand those "interesting" things, how they are designed, why they are important, and how to build them when necessary. And you can make a bit of money as a programmer as long as someone else has the knowledge about what is important or you can accrue it in other ways.

Comment: The computer science bachelor's degrees I know don't even focus on programming in the first year, or even semester. For instance the reason for the most dropouts is math. And it gets even broader in the following years, as you mentioned.